# How to avoid graphing duplicate rows in Pandas .plot()

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this with many entries for all 50 US states:

| State Name | School District | Schools Per District |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alabama | Alabama District 1 | 21 |
| Alabama | Alabama District 2 | 5 |
| Alaska | Alaska District 1 | 3 |
| Alaska | Alaska District 2 | 4 |

I want to use Pandas to graph the numbers of school vs. state, and so far I have the following code:

```
school_data.plot(kind='bar', 
                     x="State Name", 
                     xlabel="State",
                     y="Schools Per District",
                     ylabel="Number of Schools",
                     rot=0,
                     width=10,
                     figsize=(15, 5),
                     title="Number of Schools per District vs. US State"
                     );
```

However, the resulting graph I believe is graphing every single school district instead of summing all school districts by state, and is therefore printing too much data.

[image: graph of school districts generated by Pandas]

How would I fix this so that there are only 50 bars on the graph, where each bar represents the total number of schools per state?

Comment: Can you try with `school_data.groupby("State Name")["Schools Per District"].sum().plot(...`?

Comment: Just tried this now, made it a separate variable just so it'd be a little easier to read, but otherwise it's working. Thanks!